# Why this is not throwing any type error?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I was trying some code segment from one of the blog and I came to notice the following code

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f x = [1+x,2*x]

test :: IO ()
test = putStrLn . show $ return 5 >>= f >>= f
```

While executing I am getting [7,12,11,20]. Why the second 'f' function call is not throwing type error ? Is it something related to List Monad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's ask GHC what the types are for some of the subexpressions.

```
> :t putStrLn . show
putStrLn . show :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

That's certainly as expected.

```
> :t return 5 >>= f >>= f
return 5 >>= f >>= f :: [Int]
```

I suppose we expected that, but it doesn't answer your question. Next, a quick reminder on how that expression parses:

```
> :i (>>=)
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  ...
infixl 1 >>=
```

Okay, it's left associative, so the expression is `(return 5 >>= f) >>= f`.

```
> :t return 5 >>= f
return 5 >>= f :: [Int]
```

Comparing this to the above type signature for `(>>=)`, we can observe two things:

- The second argument of `(>>=)` must return some sort of monad
- The first argument of `(>>=)` must be a value in the same monad

So we know that `f` has to have a type shaped like `(a -> m b)` here, and the actual type signature for `f` is `Int -> [Int]`. So we can manually combine the types:

- `a` = `Int`
- `b` = `Int`
- `m` = `[]`

Note that `([] a)` means the same thing as `[a]`.

So the monad is indeed the list monad. So what's going on?

```
> return 5 :: ([] Int)
[5]
> [5] >>= f
[6, 10]
> ([5] >>= f) >>= f
[7, 12, 11, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Now I understood how it works. looks like there is lot to learn about monads

Answer (score 6):

It is exactly because lists are monads. You have

```
return 5 >>= f >>= f
```

In the list monad, `(>>=) = flip concatMap`, so that's the same as

```
concatMap f $ concatMap f $ return 5
```

Also in the list monad, `return x = [x]`, so we have

```
concatMap f $ concatMap f [5]
```

Now, `concatMap g x = concat (map g x)`, so we can expand that to

```
concat $ map f $ concat $ map f [5]
```

and evaluate it

```
concat $ map f $ concat $ [[6, 10]]
concat $ map f $ [6, 10]
concat $ [[7, 12], [11, 20]]
[7, 12, 11, 20]
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. I got confused with a <- return 5 and let a = 5